# What's the difference between hardstatus and caption in GNU Screen?

Tags: command-line-interface, gnu-screen

I've started to play with GNU Screen setting.

What's the difference between hardstatus and caption in GNU Screen?

`hardstatus` seems to appear at the bottom on the Terminal, but
I don't even know what `caption` really is yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, using PuTTY in Windows, hardstatus is displayed in the Windows window title (`hstatus string`), while caption is displayed at the bottom of each `screen` window when the screen is split (`caption splitonly string`) or at the bottom of any `screen` window whether it's split or not (`caption always string`).

You can find further documentation in `info screen`.

Comment: Using Putty in Windows, hardstatus alwayslastline displays the status at the bottom of the window, as the last line.

Answer (score 11):

Position, where these two statuses are displayed depends on your configuration. But the **logical meaning** of them is as follows:

- `hardstatus`: this line is used for status messages from `screen` - for example, to alert you to activity, or other similar messages.
- `caption`: this line is usually only shown if there is more than one window open and allows you to view details of them (like a currently active window).

You'll have the statuses on last two lines of the screen, if you configure them like this in your `~/.screenrc`:

```
caption string ...
hardstatus alwayslastline ...
```

You can read further details on [An introduction to the visual features of GNU Screen](http://web.archive.org/web/20190503085724/http://www.debian-administration.org/article/560/An_introduction_to_the_visual_features_of_GNU_Screen).